# Extract named sub-queries into separate files

Tags: sql, testing, google-bigquery, refactoring

Let's say I have a file containing a SQL-query with multiple named sub-queries:

```
WITH first_part AS (
  ...
),
second_part AS (
  ...
)

SELECT * FROM first_part....
```

I would like to extract `first_part` and `second_part` into standalone files, to make it easier to write tests.

I could, of course, simply extract them to separate files, and then write some code to merge all the queries into a single one at runtime. But I was wondering if there is some "conventional" way of achieving this?

Comment: Unless your SQL tool/version offers a wizard which can automate this, separating the CTEs by hand is probably your only option here.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't do this with CTEs.  You would do this with temporary tables.  The syntax varies by database, of course, but a typical syntax would be:

```
create temporary table temp_first_part as
    . . .
```

And so on.

Then you can return results, saving them into a file, using whatever mechanisms your database provides.